# Proof that a non-zero function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is continuous if $ f(x + y) = f(x) f(y) $ and $ f $ is continuous at one point.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a function such that $ f(x + y) = f(x) f(y) $ for all $ x,y \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ f $ is not identically zero. Show that if there exists a point at which $ f $ is continuous, then $ f $ is continuous on all of $ \mathbb{R} $.

I can easily see why $ f(x) \neq 0 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $, but that doesn’t seem to help. I also tried a proof by contradiction but seemed to get nowhere, so any help is greatly needed and would be immensely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A group homomorphism from one topological group to another that is continuous at one point must be continuous everywhere. Note that $ f(0) = 1 $ as $ f \not\equiv 0 $. Hence, $ f: (\mathbb{R},+,0) \to (\mathbb{R}_{> 0},\times,1) $ is a group homomorphism between topological groups that is continuous at some point.

Comment: Hi Harry. Don’t forget to accept whichever answer helped you the most! You can do so by clicking on the green check mark beside it.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that, if f is continuous at a, you can prove it's continuous at 0, then at every x :

First, remark that f(0) = 1

Second, if a is continuous at a, then

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$$

and

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)\left( \lim_{h\to 0} f(h) \right)$$

This means that

$$  \lim_{h\to 0} f(h) =1 = f(0)$$

Hence f is continuous at 0

But if f is continuous at 0, take $b \in \mathbb{R}$, and you have

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} f(b+h) = f(b)\left( \lim_{h\to 0} f(h) \right) = f(b)f(0) = f(b)$$

and f is continous at b

---

A proof with $\epsilon$ and without using the fact that $f(0)=1$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. As $f$ is continous at $a$, it exist $\delta >0$ such that for all $h \in] -\delta, \delta[$, we have $|f(a+h)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. Then

$$|f(b+h)-f(b)| = |f(a+h+(b-a))-f(b)| = |f(a+h)f(b-a) - f(b)| $$

Now suppose that $f(a+h)\geq f(a)$ and $f(b-a) \geq 0$ (it's the same for the other cases)

$$\leq |(f(a)+\epsilon)f(b-a) - f(b)| = |\epsilon f(b-a) + f(a)f(b-a) - f(b)| $$
$$= |\epsilon f(b-a) + f(b) - f(b)| = \epsilon |f(b-a)|$$

And f is continuous at b

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful, but can you show me an $\epsilon -\delta$ proof and without showing using the fact that $f(0)=1$ as we are only asked to show that $f(0)=1$ or continuous at $0$ later.

Comment: edited to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of a general theorem that says:

> Let $ G $ and $ H $ be Hausdorff topological groups and $ \phi: G \to H $ a group homomorphism. If $ \phi $ is continuous at some point, then it is continuous everywhere.

The proof is simple. Suppose that $ \phi $ is continuous at $ g \in G $, i.e., $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to g} \phi(x) = \phi(g) $, and let $ a \in G $ be another point. Then
\begin{align}
    \lim_{x \to a} \phi(x)
& = \lim_{x \to a} \phi(x) \phi(a^{-1} g g^{-1} a) \\
& = \lim_{x \to a} \phi(x a^{-1} g) \phi(g^{-1} a) \\
& = \left[ \lim_{x \to a} \phi(x a^{-1} g) \right] \phi(g^{-1} a) \quad
    (\text{By the continuity of group multiplication in $ H $.}) \\
& = \left[ \lim_{y \to g} \phi(y) \right] \phi(g^{-1} a) \quad
    (\text{By the continuity of group multiplication in $ G $.}) \\
& = \phi(g) \phi(g^{-1} a) \qquad (\text{By the continuity of $ \phi $ at $ g $.}) \\
& = \phi(a).
\end{align}

In our case, the topological groups are (as $ f $ is not identically $ 0 $)
$$
G = (\mathbb{R},+,0_{\mathbb{R}}) \quad \text{and} \quad
H = (\mathbb{R}_{> 0},\times,1_{\mathbb{R}}),
$$
and $ f $ is a group homomorphism from $ G $ to $ H $. As $ f $ is assumed to be continuous at a point, it must be continuous everywhere.

Comment: As per Harry’s request, the proof of the theorem in no way requires the fact that $ \phi(e_{G}) = e_{H} $. In fact, it is a theorem that group homomorphisms must preserve units.

Comment: Thanks a lot Berrick, this is great, just one quick question when you mean a limit in $G$ you are using the topology that ensures that that the group operation is continuous and that the topology is is $T_2$, so by $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}$ you mean a sequence in G that converges to $a$?

Comment: @Harry: Precisely! You’re really spot-on! With $ T_{2} $, I’m ensuring that every sequence in a topological group has at most one limit. People who study topological groups usually assume $ T_{2} $ anyway.

Comment: @Harry: One more thing to note. As a topological group may not be what is called ‘first-countable’, I can’t really use sequences to characterize the continuity of functions. In an advanced course on topology, you’ll learn something called a ‘net’, which is some kind of generalized sequence built from a directed set. However, in your simple example, because $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ \mathbb{R}_{> 0} $ with their standard topologies are first-countable, we can use sequences to characterize the continuity of functions.

Comment: @Harry: Hence, what I mean by $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to g} \phi(x) = h $ is the following: For every open neighborhood $ V $ of $ h $ in $ H $, there exists an open neighborhood $ U $ of $ g $ in $ G $ such that $ \phi(x) \in V $ for all $ x \in U $. This resembles an $ \epsilon $-$ \delta $ statement.